# FileSystemObject.FolderExists returning wrong value

Tags: asp-classic

The following code:

```
Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FolderExists(path) Then      
    fso.CreateFolder(path)
End If
```

Is producing the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a003a' File already exists

If I delete the folder, so that ASP is able to create it itself, it works as expected.
It's only when I manually (or using DOS `MKDIR`) create it that `FolderExists` returns false and `CreateFolder` throws the above error.

What's going on here?

EDIT:

The variable path contains the string `C:\Windows\Temp\email_attachments\` and `FolderExists` seems to be returning false for directories that have been around since before the last startup.

Comment: And what is the value of variable path? Does exists this situation at every place on your computer?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Does ist happens everywhere on your computer?

Comment: It seems to yes

Comment: Looks like permissions issue. The account under which IIS running has permission to create folders, but not read existing folders, somehow. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Hi my worked code.

```
file_path="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\2018\4"
set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
tmpArr = Split(file_path, "\")
tmpPath = tmpArr(0)
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArr)
If Not fso.FolderExists(Server.MapPath(tmpPath)) Then
fso.CreateFolder Server.MapPath(tmpPath)
End If
tmpPath = tmpPath & "\" & tmpArr(i)
Next
```

Comment: I'm a little confused why you're using `Server.MapPath`. Don't you already have the physical path?

Comment: this my code first step folder exist control.  if not exist create folder else skip step

Comment: @Fraser the author changes the physiacal path to a relative path within document root from his IIS. I think it didn't relealised that you worked outside from document root.